# Can hang-fire throttle number of background jobs running in parallel

Tags: c#, hangfire, hangfire-sql

I have IO intensive method that i am running as background job using hangfire.

```
public IHttpActionResult Request(int[] ids)
{
    foreach(var id in ids)
    {
       BackgroundJob.Enqueue<IMyService>(x => x.DoWork(id));
    }
}
```

So for each id i Enqueue a background job and hangfire immediately invoke `DoWork()` as expected. However `DoWork` is IO intensive. So if i have 100+ ids it takes lot of CPU power and bandwidth

Is there anyway to throttle number of background jobs in Hangfire

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of hangfire [queues](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/configuring-queues.html?highlight=queues) and set the number of workers for that queue.

In your hangfire startup configuration set up the following queues:

```
var options = new BackgroundJobServerOptions
{
    Queues = new[] { "default" }, // You can have multiple queues and multiple worker counts.. check hangfire documentation
    WorkerCount = 5 // this is up to you
};

app.UseHangfireServer(options);
```

See code example below:

```
public IHttpActionResult Request(int[] ids)
{
    foreach(var id in ids)
    {
       BackgroundJob.Enqueue<IMyService>(x => x.DoWork(id));
    }
}


[Queue("default")]// add this attribute on your function
public void DoWork() { 
    //Magical IO code here
}
```

I recommend you look at the following hangfire documentation if you need any futher info:
http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/configuring-degree-of-parallelism.html
https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/different-queues-having-different-worker-counts/114

Hope this helps.

Comment: i found this https://github.com/alastairtree/Hangfire.MaximumConcurrentExecutions have not used before..

Comment: I have used it with before it should also solve your problem :-)

Comment: Yes `MaximumConcurrentExecutions` worked.  One thing i noticed, i am using `Unity` for DI. If you register the background job using interface  `BackgroundJob.Enqueue<IMyService>(x => x.DoWork(id));  Then you have to add `MaximumConcurrentExecutions` attribute on method definition in Interface not in concrete class

Comment: Intresting. Thanks for the update. Looks like you solved your own question. Please post your answer so I can upvote you:-)

Comment: so encountered one more issue with `MaximumConcurrentExecutionsAttribute`.  Any value for `MaxConcurrentJobs`  less than `20` works as expected, but any value more than `20` only executes 20 job. For example `[MaximumConcurrentExecutions(100, 120, 10)]` this executes only 20 jobs at a time

Comment: nevermind i got it, by default it dedicated worker threads are capped at 20. http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/configuring-degree-of-parallelism.html